# Tokens for taxonomy term parents in Pathauto

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I am trying to find the correct tokens to use for a Pathauto pattern **in Drupal 8**.

In Drupal 7, I have a Pathauto module pattern that creates a URL alias with a node's term and parent term.

So if the node had a Term reference of *Health -> Diet*. The URL would be `health/diet/node-title`.

The pattern to generate this is `[node:field-topic:0:parents:join-path]/[node:field-topic:0]/[node:title]`

Note the `:0` is because the Term reference field allows multiple values.

Comment: Did you try node:field-topic:0:entity? Tokens behave like accessing fields in the API and entity query, they require that you specifiy :entity: to access the referenced entity.

Comment: It doesn't like that either unfortunately. I found this which suggests the functionality hasn't been implemented yet https://www.drupal.org/node/2821810

Comment: That's just another wrong way of using the token. I only just noticed now that you have field-topic, but it should be field_topic, that might fix it.

Comment: Yeah I've tried both variations `-` and `_`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just tested the tokens that I suggested in the comments with field_tags on articles and it works perfectly, no idea what your problem is, make sure you use the latest versions of pathauto and token.

Token: `/articles/[node:field_tags:0:entity:parents:join-path]/[node:field_tags:0:entity]/[node:title]`

Tag hierachy: A > B > C

Alias for an article tagged with C: `/articles/a/b/c/pathauto-test`

Comment: Thanks! Not even sure what I had wrong earlier but that pattern is working.